# Partially embedded struct

Tags: go

I can embed type A into B.

```golang
type A struct {
  R int64
  S int64
}

type B struct {
  A
}
```

But how do I embed just a single field?

```golang
type B struct {
  A.R // does not work
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your wider goal is, but this may be better solved with type parameters rather than embedding.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - my wider goal here, is to be able to create different types `B`, `C`, `D` that can use parts of `A`. Generics may be a solution. I have not explored their use in Golang.

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types -- `EmbeddedField = [ "*" ] TypeName [ TypeArgs ] .` *"A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field **must** be specified as a **type name** T or as a pointer to a non-interface **type name** *T, and T itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified **type name** acts as the field name."* -- In other words, *you can't* do what you want.

Comment: In Go's type system, a "part" of a type is not inherently a type. If type A and type B have partial overlap, it must be a third type C which both depend on.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - Okay. Is there maybe a way to reuse the types on those "parts" (i.e. fields)?

Comment: @tim-montague when you init a type and did not fill up some fields they will be automatically init with zero values, from what I understand you are looking to do a conditional check based on missing fields? If so, you can check on the zero values of the field type?

Comment: @Norman - "from what I understand you are looking to do a conditional check based on missing fields?" No. Looking to define a type, with some (but not all) fields that were already defined on another type. The accepted answer is similar to what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose your two struct data types `A` and `B`.

If you want `A` and `B` to both have a field named `F` of type `T`, you can do it like so

```golang
type (
    A struct {
        F T
    }

    B struct {
        F T
    }
)
```

If you wish to change type `T` in only one location in the source, you can abstract it like so

```golang
type (
    T = someType

    A struct {
        F T
    }

    B struct {
        F T
    }
)
```

If you wish to change the name of `F` in only one location in the source, you can abstract it like so

```golang
type (
    myField struct {
        F T
    }

    A struct {
        myField
    }

    B struct {
        myField
    }
)
```

If you have multiple extricable fields to abstract, they must be abstracted individually like so

```golang
type (
    myField1 struct {
        F1 T1
    }
    myField2 struct {
        F2 T2
    }
    
    A struct {
        myField1
        myField2
    }
    
    B struct {
        myField1
    }
)
```

Comment: I like it. My only concern is the number of *"extricable fields to abstract"* that might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed a single field. You can only embed an entire type.

If you want to embed a single field, you'll need to create a new type that contains only that field, and embed that type instead:

```golang
type R struct {
  R int64
}

type B struct {
  R
}
```

Comment: But then you would have to maintain `A.R` and `R.R` - to make sure they are both in sync. For example, I change `A.R` to `float64`... then `R.R` is no longer correct.

Comment: @tim-montague You can write a simple [test](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) for that if necessary.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - I like the suggestion to use tests to keep code in sync. But then we would need to maintain `A.R`, `R.R`, and the test.

Comment: @tim-montague It seems that what you really need to *maintain* is *simplicity*. Declaring a few data types shouldn't be keeping you up at night.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have now...

```golang
type A struct {
  R int64
  S int64
}

type B struct {
  R A
}
```

And then during implementation...

```golang
&B{
 R: &A{
   R,
   // S, - ideally we would not be able to pass in `S`
 }
}
```

I don't like this solution, because we can still pass in `S`...

---

**Update:** Based on @HymnsForDisco answer this could be coded as...

```
// A type definition could be used `type AR int64`,
//   instead of a type alias (below), but that would
//   require us to create and pass the `&AR{}` object,
//   to `&A{}` or `&B{}` for the `R` field.
type AR = int64

type A struct {
  R AR
  S int64
}

type B struct {
  R AR
}
```

And implemented as...

```golang
&B{
  R,
}
```

Comment: Your issue here is that you want to use fields `R` and `S` independently. If so, why declare them together in a data type? Data types (especially structs) are to declare an **inextricable grouping of data**. If the fields are not necessarily used together, it's counter productive to declare them only as parts of the same data type.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - `R` and `S` belong to the same data type. This is simply an example. To make this more real - lets say I have a type `Person` with fields `FirstName`, and `LastName`. Now I need another type `Greeting` which only needs the person's first name. I do not want to redefine this field, as it should match the `Person` type. Again this is an example, and have many areas in code where such a pattern would be useful.